# overload resolution failed because no accessible 'And' accepts this number of arguments When using Predicatebuilder in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, predicatebuilder

I'm Trying to build A dynamic Linq query with predicate builder in vb.net. However, when i try to use the Predicate "And" Clause To filter my query the following error appears. 
 None of the Similar questions here were answered.

here is my code:

```
Dim ds As DataTable = loaddata("Select i.itm_code AS Code,itm_barcode AS Barcode,itm_Description As Description,itm_price AS Price,subgrp_name AS Subgroup, itm_expiry, Itm_Active As Visible, itm_Featured AS Featured, ITM_PHOTO AS PHOTO, ITM_BRAND AS Brand, ITM_TITLE AS Title, ITM_SIZE AS SIZE, ITM_MEASUREMENT AS UNIT from items i, groups g, subgroups s, item_barcode b Where i.itm_code = b.itm_code AND i.itm_Subgroup = s.SubGrp_ID")

 Dim tmp As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = New DataTable().AsEnumerable()

Dim predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of DataRow, Boolean)) = PredicateBuilder.True(Of DataRow)()
```

'the error appears here

```
predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("ITM_BRAND") = brand)


tmp = ds.AsEnumerable().Where(predicate.Compile())
```

this is my Predicatebuilder Class from the class library at (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

[image]

Comment: You seem to forgot marking `And` and `Or` as [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods)

Comment: Thankyou!! well one more question

Comment: after i did that couldnt find the right way to link my datagrid to tmp Which is of type "EnurableRowCollection system.data.datarow". Any idea? my dtaagrid is returning empty rows